# $D$ is effective iff $f^*D$ is effective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper birational morphism between normal varieties and let $D$ be a Cartier divisor on $Y$.

Then is it always true that $D$ is effective $\Leftrightarrow$ $f^*D$ is effective?

If not, do we need further conditions? (ex. $f$: surjective, $X$: projective)

Comment: A proper birational map is surjective, since the image is dense (by birationality) and closed (by properness).

Answer (score 0):

As @MooS says, your hypotheses imply surjective.

Then since $f$ is birational and $Y$ is normal, we have $f_* O_X = O_Y$ by ZMT.

Then $H^0(X,f^*D) = H^0(Y,f_*f^*D) = H^0(Y,D)$ by the projection formula. In particular, one of these spaces of sections is nonzero iff the other is.